# How can I set the deployment target in a Xcode Template?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-template

I am trying to create a iOS Project Xcode Template for Xcode 4.6.1.

Is it possible to set the Deployment Target in a the `TemplateInfo.plist`file? - How?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/EditingBasicSettingsiOS.html

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no information about Xcode Templates on that website :)

Comment: hi! any solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Xcode 4.6.1 installed, but here's the key(s) I use (in TemplateInfo.plist) in Xcode 8.

The key for your project is:

```
Project > SharedSettings > IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

The key for the specific targets are in this array:

```
Targets[i] > SharedSettings > IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

Comment: PS: For Mac projects, use MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET instead of IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET